# How to override Gutenberg admin CSS

Tags: css, block-editor

I need advice how to modify Gutenberg's core CSS.

What's my problem: the outlines and block labels disappear and I want them fixed, visible on every block all the time, not only in focus.
I've found GB gets his styles from something called `wp-admin/load-styles.php` which basically got me nowhere. All the styles merge via that `load-styles.php` file. I don't know where to look for that class for the outline.

Additionally, most CSS files I found wherever are x4 - minified and and alternative for RTL.

Which file and which version of it should I modify? Or maybe there is another approach?

Comment: Your not talking about directly modifying them right?  Just enqueue a stylesheet and OVERRIDE them.

Comment: I didn't know how to do it at all :) Now I know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

To override Gutenberg's styles you need to add your own stylesheet. So hook into `enqueue_block_editor_assets` and then add your own stylesheet in which you target the selectors you wanna override. In the following example I placed a stylesheet in a custom theme's `assets/` folder.

#### `functions.php`:

```
// Add backend styles for Gutenberg.
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'gutenberg_editor_assets');

function gutenberg_editor_assets() {
  // Load the theme styles within Gutenberg.
  wp_enqueue_style('my-gutenberg-editor-styles', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/gutenberg-editor-styles.css'), FALSE);
}
```

#### `assets/gutenberg-editor-styles.css`:

```
.editor-post-title__input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

---

Source: [Creating theme editor styles for Gutenberg](https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/4544/editor-styles-gutenberg/)

Comment: Yup, like that :)