# Featured image bugging out when using svg

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor

Whenever I add an image in gutenberg's featured image on the backend, my GUI gets completely bugged. I noticed this happens only when the picutres I add are svg and not on any other format. I've seen a couple of tickets on wordpress' git such as [this](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/5577) or [that](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5477#issuecomment-906110105). I also found a workaround to fix that by applying custom positioning in a custom css file based off of [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/337033/how-to-override-gutenberg-admin-css/337035#337035?s=5c20eb7157e54c059d50506a30c5583f) ticket. My question is, is this issue resolved in newer wordpress versions? Also is there another way to fix this without creating a new css file? Thank you